# フォームで全角の空白にもエラーを返すにはどうしたらいいですか？

Tags: php, form

以下のように(index.php)からフォームし、それを受け取る(result.php)に
入力された値を反映させたいと思います。

ただし空欄だと’Err, fill in the blank’とエラーメッセージを出したいと思い
以下のようにempty()を使い記述しました。

すると完全な空欄、もしくは半角の空白だとエラーメッセージがちゃんと出ます。
[image: エラーメッセージ]

ただし、全角のスペースの空白の場合は何も表示されません。
[image: エラーメッセージ２]

日本語でも表示出来るようにはしたいので全角文字全てをエラーとしたい
訳ではなく、全角のスペースの空白はエラーに出したいと考えています。

完全な空欄、半角空白、全角空白・・・　いずれの場合にもエラーを出すには
どのように記述したら良いでしょうか？

初学者です。よろしくお願いいたします。

(index.php)

```
 <form action="result.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="message">

    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
```

(result.php)

```
<?php

$message = trim(filter_input(INPUT_GET,'message'));
$message = empty($message)? 'Err, fill in the blank': $message;


?>

  <p><?= h($message); ?></p>

  <p><a href="index.php">Go Back</a></p>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: [PHP: preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) で正規表現のパターン修飾子に `u` オプション(PCRE_UTF-8)を付けると良いかもしれません。`preg_replace("/^\s+|\s+$/u", "", $message);`